# Views strips/merges unlimited values/fields of same field into one

Tags: 7, views, entities, theming

I have a content type and a Text field 'Achievements'. Now it is set to Unlimited so every time when creating that content I enter an achievement per field. So then I have a nice list of achievements listed in separate divs where I can apply CSS and etc.

I made a view to list those content types including achievements fields and Views merges in all achievements into one view-field and makes a total mess and it becomes unlisted/unordered and no CSS cannot be applied because all divs and classes (even/odd) are gone.

It works fine via original node, but divs are stripped via Views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are displaying **fields**, you need to configure the settings for multiple values.

From the edit screen for the view, select the properties of the field set to *unlimited*.  Then scroll down and find the part that says **Multiple field settings**:

[image: multiple field settings]

Comment: Solved! Had to select Unordered list.